# For $1\leq j\leq i\leq n$, does $\sum_{k=j}^i (-1)^{i-k} \binom{n-k}{i-k} \binom{n-j}{k-j}$ equal $\delta_{i,j}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

For $1\leq j\leq i\leq n$, does $\sum_{k=j}^i (-1)^{i-k} \binom{n-k}{i-k} \binom{n-j}{k-j}$ equal $\delta_{i,j}$ ?
If so, how best to prove it ?

Comment: Short answer: finite differences. I will return to this question later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=j}^i&(-1)^{i-k}\binom{n-k}{i-k}\binom{n-j}{k-j}\\
> &=\sum_{k=j}^i(-1)^{i-k}\frac{(n-k)!}{(i-k)!(n-i)!}
> \cdot\frac{(n-j)!}{(k-j)!(n-k)!}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=j}^i(-1)^{i-k}\frac{(i-j)!}{(i-k)!(k-j)!}
> \cdot\frac{(n-j)!}{(n-i)!(i-j)!}\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{n-j}{n-i}\sum_{k=j}^i(-1)^{i-k}\binom{i-j}{k-j}\tag{3}\\
> &=\binom{n-j}{n-i}\sum_{k=0}^{i-j}(-1)^{i-j+k}\binom{i-j}{k}\tag{4}\\
> &=\binom{n-j}{n-i}(-1)^{i-j}(1-1)^{i-j}\tag{5}\\
> &=\delta_{i,j}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p!}{q!(p-q)!}$.
- In (2) we cancel $(n-k)!$ expand with $(i-j)!$ and do some rearrangements.
- In (3) we can factor out $\binom{n-j}{n-i}$ which is independent from the index variable $k$.
- In (4) we shift the index $k$ to start the series from $k=0$.
- In (5) we use the *[binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)* with $(1-1)^{i-j}$.

> Here is a different technique based upon generating functions. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$.
>
> This way we can write e.g.
>
> \begin{align*}
> [z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=j}^i&(-1)^{i-k}\binom{n-k}{i-k}\binom{n-j}{k-j}\\
> &=\sum_{k= j}^\infty(-1)^{i-k}[z^{i-k}](1+z)^{n-k}[u^{k-j}](1+u)^{n-j}\tag{6}\\
> &=(-1)^i[z^i](1+z)^n\sum_{k= j}^\infty\left(-\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^k
> [u^k]u^j(1+u)^{n-j}\tag{7}\\
> &=(-1)^i[z^i](1+z)^n\sum_{k= 0}^\infty\left(-\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^{k+j}
> [u^k](1+u)^{n-j}\tag{8}\\
> &=(-1)^i[z^{i}](1+z)^n\left(-\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^{j}\left(1-\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^{n-j}\tag{9}\\
> &=(-1)^{i-j}[z^{i-j}]1\tag{10}\\
> &=\delta_{i,j}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (6) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice and we set the upper limit of the series to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.
- In (7) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator, do some rearrangements and apply the rule $$[z^{i-k}]A(z)=[z^i]z^kA(z)$$
- In (8) we shift the index $j$ to start the series from $j=0$.
- In (9) we factor out $\left(-\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^j$ and apply the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator with $u:=-\frac{z}{1+z}$
  \begin{align*}
  A(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k[u^k]A(u)
  \end{align*}
- In (10) we can make essential simplifications.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks Marko! :-)

Comment: @Simon: I've added a different method which might be interesting. Regards,

Comment: I read the second version quite carefully and found it to be very instructive, illustrating different useful techniques. I can only upvote once.

Comment: I too very much like the both versions, and found the second in particular very instructive. Thank you very much, Markus !

Comment: @Simon: My pleasure! :-)

Answer (score 1):

A combinatorial proof isn’t too hard. Let $r=n-j$ and $s=i-j$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=j}^i(-1)^{i-k}\binom{n-k}{i-k}\binom{n-j}{k-j}&=\sum_{k=0}^{i-j}(-1)^{i-j-k}\binom{n-j-k}{i-j-k}\binom{n-j}k\\
&=(-1)^s\sum_{k=0}^s(-1)^k\binom{r-k}{s-k}\binom{r}k\;.
\end{align*}$$

Suppose that we want to count the $s$-element subsets of $[r]$ that are empty; clearly this is $1$ if $s=0$ and $0$ otherwise. On the other hand, we can use an inclusion-exclusion argument. For $k\in[r]$ let $A_k$ be the family of $s$-element subsets of $[r]$ that contain $k$. If $\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[r]$, then

$$\left|\,\bigcap_{k\in I}A_k\,\right|=\binom{r-|I|}{s-|I|}\;,$$

so

$$\left|\,\bigcup_{k=1}^rA_k\,\right|=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[r]}(-1)^{|I|-1}\left|\,\bigcap_{k\in I}A_k\,\right|=\sum_{k=1}^r(-1)^{k-1}\binom{r}k\binom{r-k}{s-k}\;.$$

This is the number of $s$-element subsets of $[r]$ that contain at least one member of $[r]$, i.e., the number of non-empty $s$-element subsets of $[r]$, so the number of empty $s$-element subsets of $[r]$ is

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{r}s-\sum_{k=1}^r(-1)^{k-1}\binom{r}k\binom{r-k}{s-k}&=\binom{r}s+\sum_{k=1}^r(-1)^k\binom{r}k\binom{r-k}{s-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{r}k\binom{r-k}{s-k}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Thus,

$$\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{r}k\binom{r-k}{s-k}=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }s=0\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;,
\end{cases}$$

and multiplying this by $(-1)^s$ doesn’t change anything, since $(-1)^0=1$.

Comment: Wow ! That is very, very nice ! Thank you so much Brian ! I feel very lucky to have been given three quite different proofs of this interesting fact. May I ask, how did you come up with the idea of counting the s-element subsets which are empty ? Also just for clarification, I suppose $[r]$ must mean $\{1, 2, \ldots, r\}$ ?

Comment: @Simon: You’re very welcome! Yes, $[r]$ is a standard notation in combinatorics for the set $\{1,2,\ldots,r\}$ when $r\in\Bbb Z^+$. After I reduced the thing to (essentially) $\sum_{k=0}^s(-1)^k\binom{r-k}{s-k}\binom{r}k$, I recognized this as the kind of sum that results from the inclusion-exclusion principle and tried to figure out what it might be counting, bearing in mind that it was supposed to evaluate to $1$ if $s=0$ and to $0$ otherwise. In doing that I was drawing on a lot of experience with similar arguments, and that experience suggested general directions in which to look.